# how to resize image and change view in mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a link to the site I am currently having issues with:

### [Link to the Site](http://drevni.prv.pl/aboutus.html)

as you can see at a full-size window, everything looks quite nice - like a twisted my senses graphic. And now:

As the width of the browser window falls below 1200 pictures (humanoids) "descend" one after the other.

1. What to do and how to do your photos to a resolution of 768px scale all like their background?
2. What to do and how to below 768px resolution photos arranged themselves one after another and the lyrics appeared next Featured click on a puppet loaded text using js.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: post sample of code of the sections you are having issues with. Use bootply, jSfiddle or an online html js and css playground to do this. This will make things easier and share the link here.

Comment: here is link to jSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=KG0R74Qpvi

Answer (score 1):

Check the bootstrap documentation for its grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

There are 4 different types of classes `col-sm col-xs col-md col-lg` each one fitted for different screen sizes and you can combine them to make dynamic grids for your site.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Test col</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Test col</div>
</div>
```

For example the code above has different behavior on small, medium and large screens. The columns resize according to the screen size. On your source code you are only using `col-lg` type cols.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not posted, and you asked for suggestions, I will give you the ones I have. first if your images are moving below each order when you go below a certain screen size/width it is because you wrote code to do that or at least you are not properly using `bootstrap`. Add a class of `img-responsive` to your images. It is a bootstrap class that helps you with image responsive designs.

Add a class of `col-sm-3` to divs surrounding the images or to the images themselves, it will keep them close on one line for from lg desktops to tablets. if you want the same thing for mobile, you had a class of `col-xs-3`

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```